# Cannot center elements in css

Tags: css, html, margin

I downloaded a template and edit it. now I want to center the `one_third` elements but the

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

doesn't work.

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/6hKCJ/) is the template in jsfiddle.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Are you trying to center the text? or the elements with respect to the page?

Comment: @invalidsyntax I didn't try to center the text! but I didn't understand you second sentence.

Comment: I am asking only to help understand the question. In my second sentence, I am asking if you want each ```one_third``` element to be in the center of the page (or parent container).

Comment: @invalidsyntax yes I want! actually I want all the `#services`'s childs in center of the page.

Comment: I believe that the reason why they are not appearing to be centered is because they are set up to act as thirds. Perhaps if you only will have 2 columns, you may want to look into setting it up to use two instead of three.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `margin-left:auto;` and `margin-right:auto;` to work, the element needs to have a width.  So try something like:

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 600px;
```

**UPDATE:**

Since you seem to alter your examples all the time, here is a very basic understanding of how `display` and `margins` work:

To have any box centered within another box, you need to do two things:

a) Give the outer box a width (otherwise the inner box doesn't know what to center against

b) The inner box needs to have `margin: 0 auto` (this is the same as `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;`)

Also, both boxes need to be block level elements (i.e. have `display: block`, NOT `display: inline;`)

So put together it will look like this:

HTML:

```
<section id="outer">
    <section id="inner"></section>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
#outer {
    width: 600px;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
#inner {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

This will give you a green box of 200px by 200px centered within a red box of width 600px.

Now, if you want two elements side by side within the green box, you can add your inline elements there, i.e.

```
<section id="outer">
    <section id="inner">
        <article>Hi</article>
        <article>Hi agian!</article>
    </section>
</section>



#outer {
    width: 600px;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
#inner {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
#inner article {
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: Of course your example won't work... first off, you gave your `.tc` elements `display:inline;`. Inline elements can't be centered.  Secondly, you don't have a width on the outer container.  If the outer container doesn't have a width, it doesn't make sense to center something inside.  Take a look at this example to see it work: http://jsfiddle.net/2sagZ/14/

Comment: I want the elements in one line. I asked the question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14756204/why-marginauto-doesnt-work).

Comment: No offense, but you might want to step back and take some time to read about the effects of `display:block` and `display:inline` and how those affect positioning of elements.  You seem to throw together new examples all the time without understanding the basics.  Either try to learn from the examples given to you or stick to one example and solve it.