# Why margin:auto doesn't work?

Tags: html, css

I want to center my element but when I use

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

it doesn't work!

this is my html

```
<section id="t">
    <article class="tc">Hi</article>
    <article class="tc">Hi agian!</article>
</section>
```

and this is my css:

```
#t {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top:10px;
}
.tc {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 600px;
    display: inline;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width:1px;
}
```

and you can see the result [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ahmadalli/2sagZ/5/).

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Ah, the age old question of how to center dynamically-wide content in browsers...  First of all: `display: inline` is going making the browser ignore width and margin styles on `.tc`

Comment: @BobFincheimer So how can I have two elements in one line in center of screen?

Comment: This is very hard to do this consistently across browsers [especially older ones].  If you target newer ones there are plenty of simple solutions, just google it

Answer (score 38):

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

would not effect the element width `display:inline`.

If your want it works, you should give a fixed width, and set `display:block` or `display:inline-block`.

Comment: If you don't know the element width, set the element container `text-align` to `center`

Comment: Could you cite a source for this? In MDN, the *fixed* width requirement was not mentioned, and everybody seems to favor flexbox today.

Comment: In the [spec for computing margin](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/visudet.html#inline-width), it is stated outright for inline elements that their margins of `auto` will become `0`. The "fixed" part is not mentioned.

Answer (score 15):

For margin auto to work you need to have a width on the item.

`#t { width: some-width; }`

http://jsfiddle.net/2sagZ/7/

Comment: Anything with margin: auto needs a width. In your updated example just give `header` a width

Answer (score 3):

You're displaying your articles inline. Only block elements can be centered by setting their margins to `auto`. So you need to make them block level elements for `margin: auto` to work.

Your main section tag has a width of 100% by default. So you can't center it if it already fills the screen. So you need to make the width less then 100% for `margin: auto` to work.

Comment: and how can I show them in a line. I want them in a line in center of the page

Comment: Technically it *is* centered if it already fills the screen, since the side margins are both zeroed out equally :P

Answer (score 2):

CSS

```
body{
    width:100%;
}

#t {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top:10px;
    width:600px;
}
.tc {
    display:inline;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width:1px;
}
```

HTML

```
<body>
<section id="t">
    <article class="tc">Hi</article>
    <article class="tc">Hi agian!</article>
</section>
</body>
```

is that wat you want?

http://jsfiddle.net/ahmadalli/2sagZ/5/

Comment: No! I want to element in a line in center of the page!

Comment: then remove the width from the #t and it should fall in line. What exactly are you trying to achieve with this html?

Comment: .tc {
        border-style: solid;
        border-width:1px;
    }

Comment: please see corrected html/css. i think this is what you want

Comment: [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ahmadalli/ApMNZ/) is what you said! this isn't what I want!

Answer (score 1):

if you are using `inline` styling you can just use `text-align: center`

http://jsfiddle.net/3MJEm/

```
#t {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top:10px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: take a look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ahmadalli/3MJEm/1/) they should be separated

Answer (score 0):

You could try giving the width a percentage, like width: 75%;.  I would also give positioning to the divs, I recommend using relative.

Answer (score 0):

`#t` needs a width in order to be centered.

The `articles` won't be centered when set to `display:inline`.

Comment: @ahmadalishafiee In this case #header needs a width.

Comment: Ok. that problem resolved but this didn't!

Answer (score -1):

```
#t {
margin: auto;
margin-top:10px;
width: 84px; 
}
.tc {
display: inline;
border-style: solid;
border-width:1px;
}
```